# How to render a returned function value in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I am pretty new to vue js. I need to render the value returned by the following function to the row in the table:

The function is:

```
getGroup(id){
        this.users.forEach(element =>{
            if(element.id===id)
                return element.group.group_name;
        });
}
```

The html tag in template is:

```
<td>{{ getGroup(ticket.assignee.assignee_id) }}</td>
```

However, nothing is rendered in that column respective rows.
How can I show the value returned in those rows?

The full code is here:

```
<template>
<div class="p-10">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="p-5">Subject</th>
                <th class="p-5">Requester</th>
                <th class="p-5">Requested</th>
                <th class="p-5">Type</th>
                <th class="p-5">Priority</th>
                <th class="p-5">Group</th>
                <th class="p-5">Updated</th>
                <th class="p-5">Assignee</th>
                <th class="p-5">Cause of suspention</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="ticket in tickets" :key="ticket.id">
                <td>{{ ticket.subject }}</td>
                <td>{{ ticket.requester }}</td>
                <td>{{ ticket.requested }}</td>
                <td>{{ ticket.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ ticket.priority }}</td>

                <td>{{ getGroup(ticket.assignee.assignee_id) }}</td>

                <td>{{ ticket.updated }}</td>
                <td>{{ ticket.assignee.assignee_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ticket.suspension_cause }}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import usersData from '../assets/users_data.json'
import ticketsData from '../assets/tickets_data.json'

export default {
    name: 'ViewTicket',
    data() {
        return {
            users:[],
            tickets:[],
            group: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getData(){
            setTimeout(function(){this.users=usersData;}.bind(this),1000);
            setTimeout(function(){this.tickets=ticketsData;}.bind(this),1000);
        },
        getGroup(id){
            this.users.forEach(element =>{
                if(element.id===id)
                    return element.group.group_name;
            });
        }
    },
    created:function(){
        this.getData();
    },
};
</script>
```

A screenshot of what is rendered:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL8qo.png)

Comment: Can you try to debug `getGroup` method and check if it is rendering properly based on the condition you apply. As looks like this is a data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find and return user group:

```
getGroup(id){
  return this.users.find(u => u.id === id).group.group_name
}
```